# Change windows updates setting with Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-update

Im working with Windows Server 2008 r2, and trying to configure a PowerShell script to change the settings of windows updates to download but let me choose to install.

Comment: Are you using WSUS, or going straight from Microsoft update?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it right from the registry with this command:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\AUoptions" -Name newproperty  -Value "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" -Name AUOptions -Value 3
```

2 = Notify before download.

3 = Automatically download and notify of installation.

4 = Automatic download and scheduled installation. (Only valid if values exist for ScheduledInstallDay and ScheduledInstallTime.)

5 = Automatic Updates is required, but end users can configure it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/security-updates/windowsupdateservices/18127499