# How to change registry settings for automatic updates using reusable Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a reusable script that will change the automatic update settings in the registry for future Windows VMs that my company creates. I want to set the Configure Automatic Updates value to enabled and set the Specify intranet Microsoft update service location to enabled, as well as setting two URLs pointing to my WSUS servers. I'm not sure how to accomplish this with a PowerShell script, as I am very new to scripting PowerShell, so if someone could lend some help or point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Also not sure if this is the right place to post this question, if it isn't let me know and ill move it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change windows updates setting with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993125/change-windows-updates-setting-with-powershell)

Comment: No I using WSUS and need to change the location of the update server

Comment: That question I linked has answers that demonstrate how to set a registry key that changes Windows update settings, which is 1 out of 2 of the things you're looking to accomplish with this script. The second one is also a registry key that needs to be set, and therefore the question I linked has enough information for you to solve your problem. You just need to do a bit of research to figure out *which* registry key needs to be set. You're (almost) never going to find an exact answer to your specific situation, because that's not how this site works.

Comment: Also the description of the [tag:script] tag begins with *"DON'T USE THIS TAG!"*. Please remove it.